# How to read txt file in nuxt 3 in a folder

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am attempting to read a file data.txt in my nuxt 3 app in folder src/resources/data.txt.
When the application is built it is attempting to read it in .output/src/resources/data.txt

Is it possible to read a file in nuxt 3? Where can I put the file for nuxt to find it?

Here is my function:

```js
    async function readData(fname: string):Promise<String | undefined>{
      const { __dirname } = useGlobalFileParams()
      try {
        const data = await fs.promises.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname,fname), 'utf-8')                           
         return data
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Put your file in the `public` directory. This way the path will remain the same even after build

Comment: How do I read the file from the public folder?  I need to be able to specify it somehow. I am only aware of the folder being for assets. This is a data file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple **Nuxt3** code that read the file from `/public/test.txt` and return it from server api.

```
// /server/api/read.get.ts

import * as path from 'node:path'
import * as fs from 'node:fs'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'test.txt')
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
  return data
})
```

Here is a **StackBlitz Link of the running code** [CodeLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-t8y6fy?file=server%2Fapi%2Fread.get.ts)